# Node spawn stdout.on data delay

Tags: linux, node.js, pipe, spawn

I am checking for USB drive removal on linux.  I am simply monitoring the output of a command line process with child_process.spawn.  But for some reason the child's stdout data event doesn't emit until like 20 lines have been printed, which makes it unable to detect a removed drive.  After removing the drive many times, it does finally go.  But obviously that won't do.

Original:

```js
var udevmonitor = require("child_process").spawn("udevadm", ["monitor", "--udev"]);
udevmonitor.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
  return console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Pretty simple.  So I figure it's an issue with the piping node is using internally.  So instead of using the pipe, I figure I'll just use a simple passthrough stream.  That could solve the problem and give me real-time output.  That code is:

```js
var stdout = new require('stream').PassThrough();
require("child_process").spawn("udevadm", ["monitor", "--udev"], { stdio: ['pipe', stdout, 'pipe'] });

stdout.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

But that gives me an error:
child_process.js:922 throw new TypeError('Incorrect value for stdio stream: ' + stdio);

The documentation says you can pass a stream in.  I don't see what I'm doing wrong and stepping through the child_process source didn't help.

Can someone help?  You can run this yourself, provided you're on Linux.  Run the code and insert a USB drive.  Perhaps you can run the command 'udevadm monitor --udev' in another terminal to see what happens.  Remove and reinsert a few times and eventually node will print out.

Comment: Did you try changing the command line to use `stdbuf` to avoid stdout buffering as shown [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378)?

Answer (score 4):

mscdex, I love you.  Changing the spawn command to

```js
spawn("stdbuf", ["-oL", "-eL", "udevadm", "monitor", "--udev"]);
```

Did the trick.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, this doesn't works with tcpdump , some idea why?